# Unable to render slick grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, slickgrid

I am using recline JS, and did everything that was mentioned in the tutorial, however I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: SlickGrid's 'enableColumnReorder = true' option
requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded
```

What I have done so far :

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/recline/slickgrid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/recline/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/recline/recline.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/slickgrid/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/slickgrid/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/underscore/underscore-1.3.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/backbone/backbone-0.9.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/slickgrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/slickgrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
<!-- Recline -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/recline/recline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/recline/recline.dataset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/recline/view.grid.js"></script>
```

and the code I am using to initialize the grid is

```
var data = [
{id: 0, date: '2011-01-01', x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:52.56, lon:13.40} },
{id: 1, date: '2011-02-02', x: 2, y: 4, z: 24, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:54.97, lon:-1.60}},
{id: 2, date: '2011-03-03', x: 3, y: 6, z: 9, country: 'US', geo: {lat:40.00, lon:-75.5}},
{id: 3, date: '2011-04-04', x: 4, y: 8, z: 6, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:57.27, lon:-6.20}},
{id: 4, date: '2011-05-04', x: 5, y: 10, z: 15, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:51.58, lon:0}},
{id: 5, date: '2011-06-02', x: 6, y: 12, z: 18, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:51.04, lon:7.9}}
];
var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
records: data
});
console.log(dataset);
var $el = $('#mygrid');
var grid = new recline.View.SlickGrid({
model: dataset,
el: $el
});
grid.visible = true;
grid.render();
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: The "requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded" error indicates that you need `jquery-ui.js` as well as everything else, I don't see any `jquery-ui.js` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Go to SlickGrid folder  which you have downloaded. You will find a "lib" folder inside that. This "lib" folder contains "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js". It's version may vary according to your SlickGrid version. In case you face similar difficulties in future, make sure that you check all the folders for required .js files. Wish you good luck!!